# Downloading "Microsoft.SharePointFarm.0.2.30-preview" Azure resource group template

Tags: sharepoint-2013, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to download the Microsoft.SharePointFarm.0.2.30-preview" Azure resource group template which is what I believe portal uses when you create a SharePoint Server farm. Unfortunately I see the template is completely empty after download. All i see is /* intentionally left blank */

Any ideas why? Is creating via PowerShell not supported in this case, looks that way at least :)

Answer (score 0):

I try the same and is also getting the same result as you using the latest Azure PowerShell as of 4th May 2015.

Perhaps this indicates that it is not supported yet